# define a typeddict from a dataclass

Tags: mypy, python-typing, python-dataclasses, typeddict

I am implementing a function that builds and returns a (frozen) dataclass.
The dataclass definition is public and "official".
Internally my implementation I need to do some complex logic to build the informations for the dataclass initialization, and I want to use a typeddict - that matches the fields in the dataclass - as a temporary holder.

I'm struggling to define the typeddict without just copying the fields... ideally I want to "dinamically" (but not really, as the dataclass fields are defined statically) define the typeddict fields

[mypy-playground](https://mypy-play.net/?gist=56e4e00c31a6aa30e4af0e04eb235367)

Comment: The typing system doesn't support this. As of today, to achieve something similar, you can either develop with a `.pyi` code generator which constructs `TypedDict` definitions from the dataclasses, or (since you're using mypy) ship a mypy plugin which modifies the source ASTs to add `TypedDict`s from the dataclass definitions.